# Show a transformation is Conformal

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

The question I've been given is as follows

A linear map $T:X→Y$ is said to be conformal when it preserves orthogonality;

$$∀x, ̃x∈X,〈x, ̃x〉= 0⇐⇒ 〈Tx,T ̃x〉= 0.$$

Show that this is the case if and only if $T^∗T=λI$ for some $λ >0$ . Moreover, if the underlying field is real,show that angles between vectors $cos(θ)=〈x,y〉/‖x‖‖y‖$ are preserved

Intuitively this makes sense to me, but I'm not sure how to prove. I think I need to use the paralleogram law to relate the inner product and the norm, something like below.

$$\langle Tx, T\tilde x\rangle = 0 = \langle T^*Tx, \tilde x \rangle$$
$$4\langle T^*Tx, \tilde x \rangle =  ||T^*Tx + \tilde x||^2 - ||T^*Tx - \tilde x||^2 +i(||iT^*Tx + \tilde x||^2 - ||iT^*Tx - \tilde x||^2)$$
$$4\langle T^*Tx, \tilde x \rangle = ||T^*T||^2(||x + \tilde x||^2 - ||x - \tilde x||^2)+i||T^*T||^2(|ix + \tilde x||^2 - ||ix - \tilde x||^2)$$
But I don't know where to go from here. We were also given the following hints, but I don't think these prove useful until later on.

[Hint: Consider $〈x−y,x+y〉$ for orthogonal unit vectors x and y and use that $H= span(x)⊕span(x)^⊥$. Note that $〈w,x〉=〈z,x〉$ for all $x∈H$ implies that $w=z$. Why?]

Comment: write \tilde x instead of x~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since
\begin{align*}
\forall x,\tilde{x} & \in X,\left\langle x,\tilde{x}\right\rangle =0\Leftrightarrow\left\langle Tx,T\tilde{x}\right\rangle =0
\end{align*}
then
\begin{align*}
\left\langle Tx,T\tilde{x}\right\rangle  & =\left\langle T^{*}Tx,\tilde{x}\right\rangle \\
\left\langle T^{*}Tx,\tilde{x}\right\rangle  & =\lambda\left\langle x,\tilde{x}\right\rangle \\
\left\langle T^{*}Tx-\lambda x,\tilde{x}\right\rangle  & =0\\
\left\langle \left(T^{*}T-\lambda I\right)x,\tilde{x}\right\rangle  & =0
\end{align*}
and therefore, since this is true for all $\tilde{x}$
\begin{align*}
\left(T^{*}T-\lambda I\right)x & =0
\end{align*}
and because it must be true for all $x$:
\begin{align*}
T^{*}T & =\lambda I
\end{align*}

Comment: It can also be seen from the point of view of angle preservation, the inner product of the transformed vectors is always proportional to the inner product of the original vector.
\begin{align*}
\left\langle Tx,T\tilde{x}\right\rangle &= \lambda \left\langle x,\tilde{x}\right\rangle 
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Here is an extended hint. You still have to fill in the details.
Using the original hint we have for orthogonal vectors
$$
\|x\|=\|y\| \ \Leftrightarrow \|Tx\|=\|Ty\|.
$$
Fix a unit vector $\tilde x$, then $T\tilde x\ne0$. Define $Sx:= \frac1{\|T\tilde x\|}Tx$. Then $S$ is norm preserving, i.e., $\|Sx\|=\|x\|$ for all $x$, where one uses $H = span(x) \oplus span(x)^\perp$.
By these polarization identities, $S$ preserves the inner product, i.e., $\langle Sx,Sy\rangle = \langle x,y \rangle $ for all $x,y$.
This is equivalent to $T^*T = \|T\tilde x\|^2 Id$.